# Multi Directory Routing in the same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When creating a registration form in the `Members` controller I would like first for members to go to `Members/Registration/Rules` and then after submitting this go to `Members/Registration/Form`. The reason is for readability and I want to apply this technique in other areas of the website. What is the easiest way of doing this? Is this possible by routing rules?

I know I can have `Rules` and `Form` action methods in the `Members` controller but these will only go to `Members/Rules` and `Members/Form` respectively and are not descriptive enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: null,
        url: "Members/Registration/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Members", action = "Rules" }
    );
```

Comment: mine was in an area so I added in the AreaRegistration. Also it looks like rules need to be in the order of most specific to most general or the rule is ignored.